# Excel - how to sum on filter, unless "ALL" is selected, in which case sum all

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have the following data table:

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duM9m.png)

And I have a dropdown in a separate area containing product type with values "A", "B", "C", and "ALL". If user selects "A", a cell will display 40 units, if user selects "C" it will display 50 units, but if user selects "ALL" it should display 130 units.

I know I can use SUMIF to sum the rows if it matches the value "A", "B", or "C" in the dropdown. However, how do I write a formula so that it will sum all the rows if the product type selection is "ALL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the logic in words is "if the dropdown shows 'all' then do a sum of all rows, otherwise do a sum only for the data value selected in the dropdown".

That is basically the syntax of an IF statement in Excel. Sometimes it helps to say it out loud.

Use an IF function to work out if the dropdown is "all" and if so, do a full sum of the range. Otherwise, do a Sumif with the dropdown as the criterion.

```
=IF(a1="all",SUM(X:X),SUMIF(Z:Z,A1,X:X))
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.